# Safely Share a Github to a new developer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, github

I'm not a coder or developer, but I have a old Rails web app for our non-profit company that we would like to update from Rails 1.8 to V4. Yes, I know quite a task I hear. Well I found I developer over seas that I'd like to work with, I just want to get some advice on how to proceed safely.

We are currently using a PostRes database on Heroku and the code is on GitHub. The developer has asked for access to the codebase on Github. We are happy to make/keep the project open source, I just want to make sure that he can't change our code until we give him permission. I believe I want to create a 'fork' for him, so he can make changes then I can roll them into my code.

Sorry for the very basic question, just looking for some advice as this is a new world for me.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is private, you can change it to public in your repository settings. After that you can send the url of your repository and the source code is now publicly visible. 
Now if you want to give someone permission to push to the repo, you will need to add him/her as a collaborator in your repo settings. Without that its not possible to push to the repository and hence not make changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

A fork is a good way to go — that way, your developer can make changes that don't affect the current codebase, and when those changes are ready, they can open a *Pull Request* to merge the changes back into your repository. You don't need to add the developer as a collaborator.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dev as a collaborator to the repo, and require him to develop new features on a separate branch, branched from the master. When he thinks the feature is ready, he can create a pull request, which helps you review his code. You can also test the functionality by pulling this branch locally and testing. Once you're satisfied, you can merge the branch into master.